# What are the commonly recited lyrics to Auld Lang Syne?

Tags: lyrics

If you Google *Auld Lang Syne* lyrics, you find the traditional five verses. However on New Year's Eve I don't usually hear all verses. Which lyrics are commonly included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having played a good near 50 New Years Eve gigs (miss them now!) only the first verse and chorus were played and sung, the final chorus usually ending with a pile of happy folk in a big knot in the middle. Didn't even know there were more verses!

Comment: However many verses are sung, it's worth noting the Scots word "Syne" should be pronounced the same way as "Sign" and never "Zyne".

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S., only the first verse plus chorus are commonly sung.

Comment: Same in England [can't vouch for Scotland]. I always think of it as one of those, like the national anthem, where most people are completely unaware more verses even exist;)

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but source? I'm sure you could find *something* to back up this (correct) claim. Reads like a comment at the moment.